# How do I allow Creating Tags only for certain operations - AWS IAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tagging

Following an example from the internet with RunInstance and ec2:CreateTag + ec2:CreateAction I am trying to ONLY allow the operations below if during **their creation** a certain Tag is set (not present in this output).
If I try a few test then I always get an error when I try to create a Security Group with a Tag.
I tried to find the ec2:CreateAction documentation and see what parameters it would expect but sadly each one of my searches in the AWS official doc revealed almost nothing.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:CreateTags",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": [
                        "RunInstances",
                        "CreateRouteTable",
                        "CreateKeyPair",
                        "CreateRoute",
                        "CreateVolume",
                        "CreateNetworkInterface",
                        "CreateSecurityGroup",
                        "CreateSnapshot",
                        "CreateVpcPeeringConnection",
                        "CreateSubnet",
                        "CreateVPC",
                        "AllocateAddress"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create three rules; VPC permissions need to be set as well:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:0123456789:vpc/*"
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:0123456789:security-group/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "aws:RequestTag/tagkey": "tagvalue"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
            "aws:TagKeys": [
                "tagkey"
            ]
        }               
    }
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:0123456789:security-group/*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:CreateAction" : "CreateSecurityGroup"
        }
    }
}
```